# Timer Job Completes, but fails on one or more machines in the farm

Tags: error

I am trying to configure the Business Data Connectivity service. The last service was corrupt in and an error state so I removed the service and added it back in. When adding it back to the SharePoint site I receive an error stating "The Timer Job Completed but has failed on one or more machines in the farm."(We only have the one server/machine in the farm). The service doesn't provision but goes into an "error" state and the Application Proxy for Business Data connectivity is stopped. Have been pulling my hair out with this. [image: Timer Job]

[image: BDC error]

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the ULS or Event Viewer on the server when you try to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to create a BCS but it looks like the service itself is not started. Start it if its not started. Else stop and then restart it.

Open the central administration -> Application management -> under "Service Applications" click "Manage services on server".

find "Business Data Connectivity Service" and start the service -> click "Start"

now go back to "Manage service applications" and it should be in started stage

Answer (score 1):

Things to check

- The [Business Data Connectivity Service is started](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683107.aspx) in Services on server http://CentralAdminURL/_admin/Server.aspx
- The Account creating the application is a member och local administrators group of the SharePoint server
- The SharePoint Timer job is running in services.msc
- The account creating the BDC service have DB_Creator server role on the SQL Server, and is db_owner of the Config_DB.

Answer (score 0):

In order to recreate(delete and create), I would follow these steps

- delete the bcs service application
- stop the service instance from central admin > manage service on server
- now start again the same service
- create the bcs service application

If it did not work then try 2 things extra

- restart the sharepoint timer service from services console
- also clear the config cache on the server

Answer (score 0):

We just had the same issue. ULS showed an error creating the Database. In our case the default database location in SQL Server was wrong.